# file name parser

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I want to parse the file name and assign a variable (code) based on it. I think I can use cut to get each values. But can we do it in one command?

sample file name:
012345678_***012345678***-abcdefghijklmnop_YYYYMMDD_TTTT

from the 2nd qualifier ***012345678*** i need to assign a value to the variable (code).

if col-2 & col-3 is yy and col-4 & col-5 is 00 or 01 or 02 and col 678 is 'abc' assign code = usa

if col-2 & col-3 is yy and col-4 & col-5 is 00 or 01 or 02 and col 678 is not equal to 'abc' assign code = uk

if col-2 & col-3 is not equal to yy and col-4 & col-5 is not equal to 00 or 01 or 02 and col 678 is not equal to 'abc' assign code = Aus

**Note**:
the 2nd qualifer is always after the first underscore and before the first dash. The yy is the value in the 2nd qualifier in position col -2 and col-3

Example file name:012345678_01yy00abc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180408_1300 assign code = usa

Example file name: 012345678_01yy00xyz-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180408_1300 assign code = uk

Example file name: 012345678_01aa98def-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180408_1300 assign code = Aus (so if it not usa or uk, it is Aus)

Comment: Is that second qualifier always after the first underscore and before the first dash? Also, there are no `yy` in your example, correct?

Comment: Perhaps an example that matches one of your criteria would help.

Comment: yes...the 2nd qualifer is always after the first underscore and before the first dash. The yy is the value in the 2nd qualifier in position col -2 and col-3.

Comment: Example file name:012345678_01yy00abc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180408_1300 assign code = usa

Comment: Example file name 012345678_01yy00xyz-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180408_1300 assign code = uk

Comment: 012345678_01aa98def-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180408_1300 assign code = Aus

Comment: so if it not usa or uk, it is Aus

Comment: These updates would be much more useful if they were edited into your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question ask on Stackexchange should show proof of work. In this case, It almost look like you're looking for someone to advise you on how to do or even do it for you. This not how we work we will love to help you if you show a bit of script or proof that you had work on the issue already. In this actual form though I think your question doesn"t qualify as an acceptable question.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best
 way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bash script loops through all the files in the current directory that match the pattern (something) underscore (something) dash (something) underscore (something) underscore (something) and then picks apart the relevant fields for comparison. The `${field:4:2}` syntax means to take the value of `$field` starting at position 4 and extract two characters.

The various pieces are then compared according to the logic you listed, and the `code` variable is assigned.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *_*-*_*_*
do
  field=${f#*_}
  field=${field%%-*}

  col23=${field:2:2}
  col45=${field:4:2}
  col678=${field:6:3}

  if [ "$col23" = "yy" ]
  then
    case $col45 in
      (00|01|02)
        if [ "$col678" = "abc" ]
        then
                code=usa
        else
                code=uk
        fi
        ;;
      (*)
        code=Aus
        ;;
    esac
  else
    code=Aus
  fi
  echo "For file $f, code is: $code"
done
```

Comment: Happy to help, @Krrp78. Don’t forget to click the check mark if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just one regex could gice you all fields.
Just one case statement could test all conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash

a='[^_]+_'    b='[^-]{2}'    c='[^-]{3}'
regex="^$a($b($b)($b)($c))-$a$a.*$"

for f in *_*-*_*_*; do
    if [[ $f =~ $regex ]]; then

        arr=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
        # echo "field=${arr[0]} col23=${arr[1]} col45=${arr[2]} col678=${arr[3]}"

        a=0; b=0; c=0
        [[ ${arr[1]} == "yy"        ]] && a=1
        [[ ${arr[2]} == @(00|01|02) ]] && b=1
        [[ ${arr[3]} == "abc"       ]] && c=1
        case $a$b$c in
            (111) code=usa ;;
            (110) code=uk  ;;
            (*)   code=Aus ;;
        esac
        echo "For file $f, code is: $code"
    fi
done
```